# Entity Framework and many-to-many relation with explicit link table

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I'm using code-first Entity Framework and I know you can easily create a many-to-many relation between ObjectA and ObjectB by adding an ICollection to each; EF will automatically create a link table behind the scenes.

```
public class ObjectA {
    public ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectsB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB {
    public ICollection<ObjectA> ObjectsA { get; set; }
}
```

Now I needed an additional property to this relation, so I made my own link table

```
public class ObjectA {
    public ICollection<ObjectA_ObjectB> AtoB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB {
    public ICollection<ObjectA_ObjectB> BtoA { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectA_ObjectB {
    public ObjectA A { get; set; }
    public ObjectB B { get; set; }

    public DateTime MyStartDate { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine, but the big loss is that I now no longer have a direct collection of ObjectB and ObjectA in my entities, even though the relation is still the same, just with an explicit link table.

I really want my direct collections back. Is there some way (with ModelBuilder or data annotations?) to combine the two methods above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to have the original collections as navigation properties. What you could do is adding helper collections that are not mapped to the database and are readonly:

```
public class ObjectA {
    public ICollection<ObjectA_ObjectB> AtoB { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ObjectB> ObjectsB
    {
        get { return AtoB.Select(ab => ab.B); }
    }
}
```

A query which would load the `AtoB` would give you the desired result:

```
var objectA = context.ObjectAs
    .Include(a => a.AtoB.Select(ab => ab.B)).First();

// objectA.ObjectsB would return the Bs now
```

But it's rather limited because you can't use this collection in any queries nor can't you manipulate relationships through this collection. You always have to use the `AToB` collection for this.

Comment: This works surprisingly well for my goal. I only had to add the [NotMapped] data annotation to my helper collection, or else EF would choke with a Sqlexception "Invalid column name 'ObjectB_Id'".